# jest.spyOn() TypeError when called on react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I'm trying to use `jest.spyOn()` for my tests instead of `jest.mock` since the return value of a mock can't be type-checked. When I use it though, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property useGame of #<Object> which has only a getter
> 3 | const STATE_SPY = jest.spyOn(hooks, "useGame");
    |                        ^ 
at ModuleMockerClass.spyOn (node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:852:26)
at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/game/game.test.tsx:4:24)
```

My files are structured like:

```
src/
  - game.test.tsx
  - game.tsx
  - hooks/
    - index.tsx
    - use-game.tsx
```

And here is how my code is laid out (I removed a lot of extraneous code for this question
to make it easier to read).

`/hooks/index.tsx`:

```
export { default as useGame } from "./use-game";
```

`use-game.tsx`:

```
export default function useGame(initScore: number) {
  const [score, setScore] = useState(initScore);

  return {
    score,
    setScore,
  }
}
```

`game.test.tsx`:

```
import * as hooks from "./hooks";

const STATE_SPY = jest.spyOn(hooks, "useGame");
```

`game.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";
import { useGame } from "./hooks";

const STARTING_SCORE = 50;

export default function Game(): JSX.Element {
  const {score} = useGame(STARTING_SCORE);

  return (
    <div>
      {score}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I think the issue is how `useGame` is exported as a module. But I haven't figured out a way to export/import it "correctly". Of course, there could be another issue that I'm unaware of.

App was created with `create-react-app`.

My `package.json` in case that helps.

```
{
  "name": "greatest-game-of-all-time",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@types/jest": "^24.9.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.53",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^3.9.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/dom": "^7.21.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "^3.4.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "prettier": "2.0.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I looked through your package.json and noticed that the package `@testing-library/react-hooks` had been added earlier. I propose to use it in order to write new tests for hooks.

You can read the documentation to get started https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, that's for testing the hook itself. I already wrote tests for the hook itself (not included in my question since it's not pertinent). What I want to do is to spy on the hook while I test the component function to see if clicking a button results in changes to the hook state.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you use babel to transpile your code. As I know that if you import with wild card (namespace) like that. It will create a object contains your named exports as getter like

```js
var obj = { get namedExport: () => ... }
```

so in this case, I suggest to either mock entire module:

```js
jest.mock('./hooks', () => ({ useGame: yourMock }))
```

or switch to `tsc` by using `ts-jest` to fix your issue (since `tsc` won't use getter to export that named export)

Comment: I'd like to avoid mocking since the return value of a mock can't be type-checked.


I installed `ts-jest` (24.3.0) and ran `npx ts-jest config:init`. But when I run `npm test`, I get the exact same error.


Logging `hooks` gives `{ useGame: [Getter] }` and `hooks.useGame` logs as `[Function: useGame] `

Comment: Found a solution that works. Rewriting it as:


`import * as useGame from "./hooks/use-game";`
`const STATE_SPY = jest.spyOn(useGame, "default");`



`useGame` logs as `{ default: [Function: useGame] }`


While this works, for style points I would prefer a solution that imports from the module created by `index.tsx`, since that's how everything else is imported.